# Gather Data from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am building a Stored procedure which will be used to drive a management report.

The report structure is as follows:

> Region
>
> > Branch
> >
> > > Product
> > >
> > > > SaleAmount | SaleCount | ApplicationCount | CancelCount | DeclineCount | PendingCount
> > >
> > > Product
> >
> > Branch
>
> Region

I have written the queries to give me the data for the Sales, Applications, Cancellations, Declines and Pending.

These queries all return to temporary tables with the following structure:

> BranchCode | ProductID | Value | Count

I then have a query which returns all the data for Regions and Branches (QryBranch), as we want the report to show all branches, branches with no data will just display zeros in their results.

The issue I am having is collating all the data together to give me the desired results as I have no link between QryBranch and TblProduct.

I can easily link between QryBranch and the temp tables on BranchCode, but I cannot work out how to factor in Product.

Please can someone give some advice.

Comment: Isn't there a BranchCode in QryBranch? You'll need to post more information to get good help.

Comment: Hi. Yes the QryBranch returns BranchCode And BranchName, I can link to this no problem, the issue I have is including Products.

Comment: You have a productid - do you have a product master table to match this to a product name? What happens when you join all of your tables up? What are you missing? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I need to show everything from the QryBranch, then the results per product. My issue is that there is not a link between QryBranch and TblProduct

Comment: What about all your temporary tables that you mentioned above that contain BranchCode and ProductID?